# find: cannot stat current directory: Permission denied

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I was installing RVM and added the line

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

into my .bashrc file.

Now RVM works fine, but  i have next message

```
find: cannot stat current directory: Permission denied
```

after each RVM-command.  How can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to be root to source/exec the script? (Sounds weird since it's located in a users HOME dir, but..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough information in your question to give you an answer.
Current directory of find is not readable. Why? You need to add

```
set -x
```

to the script and then you will see, in which directory find tries to run.
Than one can say what one must do further.